# swapping 2 rows in a dataframe with the same word pattern

Tags: python, pandas

in this data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Info': ['Station 1','Measure A', 'Observation alpha','NA','NA','NA','Station 2','Measure B', 'Observation bravo','NA','NA','NA','Station 3','Measure B', 'Observation charlie','NA','NA','NA'],'Values': ['NA','NA','NA',1,4,5,'NA','NA','NA',1,9,4,'NA','NA','NA',6,4,8,]}, columns = ['Info', 'Values'])
```

i am looking  to swap rows with the same keyword pattern by switching off the Measure and stations using the rows containing those 2 words "Measure" and "Station" to swap them to become like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Info': ['Measure A','Station 1', 'Observation alpha','NA','NA','NA','Measure B','Station 2', 'Observation bravo','NA','NA','NA','Measure B','Station 3', 'Observation charlie','NA','NA','NA'],'Values': ['NA','NA','NA',1,4,5,'NA','NA','NA',1,9,4,'NA','NA','NA',6,4,8,]}, columns = ['Info', 'Values'])
```

thank you

Comment: is it supposed to be Station 3 with Measure C ? and do you also need to swap the values ?

Comment: NO, Measure B, ! same name as the last measure , the swapping between each Measure and station words ; and yes , swapping the entire rows

Comment: ok but do you know already which stations are supposed to be with which measures ? There has to be pattern if you want to operate on all the rows.

Comment: it could be alsoa like this : ```df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Info': ['Station 1','measure A', 'Observation alpha','Station 2','measure B', 'Observation bravo','Station 3','measure B', 'Observation charlie'],'Values': [1,4,5,1,9,4,6,4,8]}, columns = ['Info', 'Values'])``` result is : ```df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Info': ['measure A','Station 1', 'Observation alpha','measure B','Station 2', 'Observation bravo','measure B','Station 3', 'Observation charlie'],'Values': [4,1,5,9,1,4,4,6,8]}, columns = ['Info', 'Values'])```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try creating 2 boolean masks and modify the index (-1 &+1) and then concat them back with the other rows:

```
c1 = df['Info'].str.contains("Station")
c2 = df['Info'].str.contains("Measure")
d1 = df[c1]
d2 = df[c2]
d1.index = d1.index+1
d2.index = d2.index-1
out = pd.concat((d1,d2,df[~(c1|c2)])).sort_index()
```

---

```
print(out)

                   Info Values
0             Measure A     NA
1             Station 1     NA
2     Observation alpha     NA
3                    NA      1
4                    NA      4
5                    NA      5
6             Measure B     NA
7             Station 2     NA
8     Observation bravo     NA
9                    NA      1
10                   NA      9
11                   NA      4
12            Measure B     NA
13            Station 3     NA
14  Observation charlie     NA
15                   NA      6
16                   NA      4
17                   NA      8
```